# How can I remove string between comma

Tags: java, string

For example, I have a string like this:

"Banana,Lemon,Orange,Watermelon,..."

**Note:** I write ... mean more hundreds of fruits, it is not belong to the string above.

So my question is how can I remove the fruit for example - between the 55th comma and the 56th comma?

Comment: You can use `String#split()`

Comment: A string with 'hundreds' of fruits? It may be a good idea to rethink that model and use an array as other have suggested. Just a thought.

Comment: I just use it as example here. Actually, I want to remove a specific index of a json string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility using `String.split(...)` and streams.

```
public static String removeFruit(String fruits, int n)
{
  String[] a = fruits.split(",");
  return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a, 0, n), Arrays.stream(a, n + 1, a.length))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = string.split(",");
String fruit1=parts[0]
String fruit2=parts[1]
String fruit3=parts[2]
```

.... and so on.

Comment: I dont understand. How can I remove the fruit I want and keep the rest by doing this way?

Comment: @Kakashi : I don't understand, what exactly you are asking now. Please explain with one small example.

Comment: @Kakashi - parts[55] will give you the fruit between 55th and 56th comma

Comment: So I have to remove it from the array and merge the rest? How can I do that?

Comment: @Kakashi: I really don't know understand what exactly you want. If you want to combine all the fruits without comma into string then, you can simply do it like this. `String res="";for (int i =0 ; i < parts.length(); i++) { res += parts[i];}`

Comment: It's very simple. I want "Banana,Lemon,Orange" to "Banana,Orange" without counting the index of the character but by the occurance of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not production code; you need to validate parameters, it doesn’t take into account that the fruit to remove may be the last in the list, and more. I believe you can use it as a starting point.

```
/** From fruits removes the item betwwen noth and (no + 1)th comma, 1-based */
private String removeItem(String fruits, int no) {
    int commaIx = -1; // imagine a 0th commas before the beginning of the string
    int previous = -2;
    for (int noComma = 0; noComma < no; noComma++) {
        previous = commaIx;
        commaIx = fruits.indexOf(',', commaIx);
        if (commaIx == -1) { // not found
            return fruits;
        }
    }
    return fruits.substring(0, previous + 1) + fruits.substring(commaIx + 1);
}
```